# How to get the redirect URL using NSURLConnection, when server returns 'Moved temporarily' or 'Moved permanently'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, redirect, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I have a URL with format schema://hostname (e.g. https://some.server.com).
I'm trying to get the redirect page (in my case to a login form) (e.g. httpx://some.server.com/this/is/you/loginpage)

Browsers will automatically redirect to this page, which is received from the server by a 'Location' header in the response. When analysing this request in Google Chrome, I see a '302' status with a location header. This location header has the correct URL, but for some reason I'm not able to retrieve this header (or http status!) using the NSURLConnectionDelegate methods.
I've also tried AFNetworking, but with same results.

In this case the connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse: method is only called for canonical changes, but not for location changes.

I also found out the UIWebView DOES automatically redirect to this 'Location' URL. I'm also able to catch this redirect using the UIWebView delegate method: webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: 
I don't want to use UIWebView since this is a UI component which is only accessible in the main thread, while I'm doing some background operations. (However I'm using it now as a workaround).

The desired behaviour is also described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location
Any ideas how to detect/perform this redirect using NSURLConnection (or any AFNetworking class)?

Relevant code using NSURLConnection (does not redirect in this situation):

```
- (void)resolveUsingNSURLConnection:(NSURL *)URL {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    self.isRequestBusy = YES;
    NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (urlConnection) {
        [self waitUntilRequestFinished];
    }

    NSLog(@"resolveUsingNSURLConnection ready (status: %i, URL: %@)", self.response.statusCode, self.response.URL);
}

- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse {
    if (redirectResponse) {
        // Just log the redirect request
        NSLog(@"[%@] server redirect allowed:\n\t%@ %@\n\t%@ %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), self.request.HTTPMethod, self.request.URL.absoluteString, request.HTTPMethod, request.URL.absoluteString);
        return request;
    } else {
        // Just log the canonical change
        NSLog(@"[%@] canonical change:\n\t%@ %@\n\t%@ %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), self.request.HTTPMethod, self.request.URL.absoluteString, request.HTTPMethod, request.URL.absoluteString);
        return request;
    }
}
```

Relevant code using UIWebView (has desired redirect behaviour, not the desired component):

```
- (void)resolveUsingUIWebView:(NSURL *)URL {
    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(resolveUsingUIWebView:) withObject:URL waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
    }

    NSURLRequest *hostnameURLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0f];
    self.isRequestBusy = YES;
    UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    webview.delegate = self;
    [webview loadRequest:hostnameURLRequest];
    [self waitUntilRequestFinished];

    NSLog(@"resolveUsingUIWebView ready (status: UNKNOWN, URL: %@)", webview.request.URL);
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: %@ (%i)", request.URL, navigationType);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Usual response: Use a network analyzer such as Charles Proxy. There several ways redirects can happen: Status code (ex: 301, 302, 303, 207), MetaData, javaScript. I have successfully used `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:`

Comment: Maybe the issue is that I don't get the 3xx status (but a 403 instead). I only see the 3xx status in the analyzer.
I also can't explain why NSURLConnection would behave differently from how UIWebView handles redirects.

Comment: There are several ways `UIWebView` handles redirects differently. The web service may examine the User Agent string and act differently (I have seen this). The redirect may be JaveScript (I have seen this).

Comment: @Zaph Thank you very much for the User-Agent hint, it solved my issue. Setting the User-Agent header, changed the redirect behaviour and it now seems to be doing what i was looking for. I copied the header value from a default UIWebView request. If you can post your explanation as an answer i'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways UIWebView handles redirects differently that I have seen, a couple are:

The web service may examine the User-Agent string and act differently.

The redirect may be JaveScript.

Comment: In my case the solution was:  
  
`#define kUserAgentValue @"Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/11A465"`  
  
`[mutableRequest addValue:kUserAgentValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];`